# R: How to match or filter variables with same character strings but different sequence?

Tags: r, string, filter, character

I've a data set with two variables consisting of full names (name and surname). However, these two variables are ordered in a different sequence:

- `variable1` is ordered by
- `variable2` is ordered by

How do I filter the rows such that `variable1` = `variable2`? Or can I modify the order of variable2 to match that of variable1?

I created a small sample to replicate the dataset(to note, some full names contain 3 or more words):

```r
library(tidyverse)

name_surname <- c("John Smith One", "Jane Smith Two", "John Doe", "Nick Doe", "Chris Froome", "Van den Broeck", "Lance", "Van Dae Le Phillipe")

surname_name <- c("Smith One John", "Smith Two Jane", "Doe John", "Nick Doe", "Froome Chris", "Broeck Van den", "Lance", "Phillipe Van Dae Le")

tibble <- tibble(variable1 = name_surname, variable2 = surname_name)

tibble
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>   variable1           variable2          
#>   <chr>               <chr>              
#> 1 John Smith One      Smith One John     
#> 2 Jane Smith Two      Smith Two Jane     
#> 3 John Doe            Doe John           
#> 4 Nick Doe            Nick Doe           
#> 5 Chris Froome        Froome Chris       
#> 6 Van den Broeck      Broeck Van den     
#> 7 Lance               Lance              
#> 8 Van Dae Le Phillipe Phillipe Van Dae Le
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Session info

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
#>  os       macOS Catalina 10.15.5      
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_AU.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_AU.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Australia/Melbourne         
#>  date     2020-08-25                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  backports     1.1.8   2020-06-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  blob          1.2.1   2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  broom         0.7.0   2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  callr         3.4.3   2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  cellranger    1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  cli           2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  colorspace    1.4-1   2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  DBI           1.1.0   2019-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  dbplyr        1.4.4   2020-05-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  devtools      2.3.1   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  digest        0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.1   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.1)
#>  fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  forcats     * 0.5.0   2020-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  generics      0.0.2   2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.2   2020-06-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  glue          1.4.1   2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  haven         2.3.1   2020-06-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  hms           0.5.3   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  httr          1.4.2   2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  jsonlite      1.7.0   2020-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  knitr         1.29    2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  lifecycle     0.2.0   2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  lubridate     1.7.9   2020-06-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  modelr        0.1.8   2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pillar        1.4.6   2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgbuild      1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  processx      3.4.3   2020-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ps            1.3.3   2020-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  purrr       * 0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.5   2020-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  readr       * 1.3.1   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  readxl        1.3.1   2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  reprex        0.3.0   2019-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rlang         0.4.7   2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.3     2020-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rvest         0.3.6   2020-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  scales        1.1.1   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringi       1.4.6   2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringr     * 1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  testthat      2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  tibble      * 3.0.3   2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  tidyr       * 1.1.1   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  tidyselect    1.1.0   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  tidyverse   * 1.3.0   2019-11-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  usethis       1.6.1   2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  utf8          1.1.4   2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  vctrs         0.3.2   2020-07-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  withr         2.2.0   2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  xfun          0.16    2020-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  xml2          1.3.2   2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#> 
#> [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the variables on space and order `variable2` based on `variable1`.

```
tibble$variable3 <- mapply(function(x, y) paste(y[match(x, y)], collapse = " "), 
    strsplit(tibble$variable1, '\\s+'), strsplit(tibble$variable2, '\\s+'))

tibble
# A tibble: 8 x 3
#  variable1           variable2           variable3          
#  <chr>               <chr>               <chr>              
#1 John Smith One      Smith One John      John Smith One     
#2 Jane Smith Two      Smith Two Jane      Jane Smith Two     
#3 John Doe            Doe John            John Doe           
#4 Nick Doe            Nick Doe            Nick Doe           
#5 Chris Froome        Froome Chris        Chris Froome       
#6 Van den Broeck      Broeck Van den      Van den Broeck     
#7 Lance               Lance               Lance              
#8 Van Dae Le Phillipe Phillipe Van Dae Le Van Dae Le Phillipe
```

Created a new variable (`variable3`) for comparison purposes, if needed you can overwrite `variable2` in the `tibble`.

Answer (score 2):

A similar logic to @Ronak Shah, but using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
tibble %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 separate_rows(variable1, variable2) %>%
 group_by(rowid) %>%
 mutate(variable2 = variable2[match(variable1, variable2)]) %>%
 summarise(across(starts_with("variable"), paste, collapse = " "))

  rowid variable1           variable2          
  <int> <chr>               <chr>              
1     1 John Smith One      John Smith One     
2     2 Jane Smith Two      Jane Smith Two     
3     3 John Doe            John Doe           
4     4 Nick Doe            Nick Doe           
5     5 Chris Froome        Chris Froome       
6     6 Van den Broeck      Van den Broeck     
7     7 Lance               Lance              
8     8 Van Dae Le Phillipe Van Dae Le Phillipe
```